# VIM on Windows fails to execute grep with regex patterns

Tags: regex, windows, vim, gnuwin32

When I worked on Linux I've created set of greps shortcuts which I used frequenlty. like

```
command! GrepFaults :%!grep -a -E '(newAlarm Id)|\bE?[Ff]aultI[dD]|updateAlarmCounter'
```

However when I executed this on Windows I received E4895 errors

```
E484: Can't open file C:\Users\tanglor\Appdata\Local\Temp[\VIo112B.tmp
```

When I change ' to " - then gVim hangs waiting for terminal command to complete

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (grep -a -E ^"^(newAlarm Id^) ^<C:\Users\tanglor\AppData\Local\Temp\VIi434C.tmp ^|\bE?[Ff]aultI[dD]^|updateAlarmCounter^" ^>C:\Users\tanglor\AppData\Local\Temp\VIo434D.tmp 2^>^&1)
```

*C:\Users\tanglor\AppData\Local\Temp\VIi434C.tmp* contain buffer on which I currently work.
gVim internals has problem with keeping grep regex command as one command, he inserts input where second part of regext alternative should be. 
I tried to escape pipe (|) with **^** char or **** char - no result.

I can use Windows findstr, but I would like to keep my vim files coherent.
I believe that I may need some extra escape character. 
Can you help solve this?

Comment: Windows VIM or VIM in Cygwin? Linux subsystem? ...

Comment: windows 10. Grep installed as GnuWin32 Grep-2.5.4

Comment: The first command is not even complete. You have something like: `command! GrepFaults :%!grep -a -E '...` which is missing a closing  apostrophe.